# Question regarding comparison of multiple variables in biology

Tags: mean

The query is as follows:

Recently my colleague and I performed an experiment in parallel. The experiment was exactly the same , just performed in parallel. Let us call me A, my colleague as B.

In each of our experiment we used, 3 samples (S1, S2, S3) done in triplicates at 3 different concentrations (X, 10X, 100X).

Now I want to compare these 2 experiments (A v/s B) and in each of them those 3 samples (triplicates to be plot as mean, SD) at the 3 different concentrations.

Let me make it easy for you, here: [http://imgur.com/vUPjsxI](https://imgur.com/vUPjsxI) This is an image link that best explains my query. Could anyone please help me out?

I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It is not quite clear what aspect you want to compare but the overall layout looks as though an analysis of variance (ANOVA) might fit your requirements. You would have three factors: experimenter (2 levels), sample (3) and concentration (3).

Comment: So for each concentration, you have a single measurement? Are you familiar with R or Python?

Answer (score 0):

The link you entered is broken, But I think I get your meaning.

I believe the test you want to run is a Two-way ANOVA. It's not too hard to do this in R/R Studio once you give it a shot.

**Step 1:**
I would make a long data table in excel with 5 columns: 
"scientist" "replicate" "concentration" "sample" "Y"

**Step 2:**
fill the data table with your data and save as a txt file:
scientist: (A or B)
replicate: (1, 2, or 3)
concentration: (1, 10, 100)
sample: (S1, S2, or S3)
Y: (the dependent measurement variable that you collected)

**Step 3:**
Use this example code to read the table into R:

`MYdata = read.table("/Users/lyncht/Desktop/Parekh/BCPhenotype DATA/BCphenotype2.txt", header=TRUE, sep = "\t")`

*-note:* the path and file name (in quotations) will be different for you because this depends on where you saved your data file and what you named it. Also, mind that the extension is included.

**Step 3:**

```
anova(lm(Y ~ scientist*replicate*concentration*sample, MYdata))
```